# Unexpected behavior of the list

Tags: c#, .net, list, .net-core

I'm using in my app four methods, to prepare recipes for drink:

1)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> FirstStep()
    {
        var alcohols = await _context.Ingredients
            .Where(i => i.Type == "Alcohol")
            .ToListAsync();

        return View("FirstStep", alcohols);
    }
```

2)

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SecondStep(List<Ingredient> alcohols)
    {

        for (int i=0; i< alcohols.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (alcohols[i].IsChecked == true)
            {
                UserAlcohols.Add(alcohols[i]);
            }
            else
                continue;
        }

        var juices = await _context.Ingredients
            .Where(i => i.Type == "Juice")
            .ToListAsync(); 

        AllIngredients.Add(UserAlcohols);
        AllIngredients.Add(juices);

        return View("SecondStep", AllIngredients);
    }
```

3)

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ThirdStep(List<List<Ingredient>> AllIngredients)
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < AllIngredients[1].Count(); i++)
        {
            if (AllIngredients[1][i].IsChecked == true)
            {
                UserJuices.Add(AllIngredients[1][i]);
            }
            else
                continue;
        }

        AllIngredients[1] = UserJuices;

        var additions = await _context.Ingredients
            .Where(i => i.Type == "Addition")
            .ToListAsync();

        AllIngredients.Add(additions);

        return View("ThirdStep", AllIngredients);
    }
```

4)

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FinalDrinks(List<List<Ingredient>> AllIngredients)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < AllIngredients[2].Count(); i++)
        {
            if (AllIngredients[2][i].IsChecked == true)
            {
                UserAdditions.Add(AllIngredients[2][i]);
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
        AllIngredients[2] = UserAdditions;

        for (int i = 0; i < AllIngredients.Count(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < AllIngredients[i].Count(); j++)
            {
                UserComponents.Add(AllIngredients[i][j].Id);
            }
        }
```

And i have a problem with list AllIngredients. I pasted here all method for better understanding my problem. I have in database a table with ingredients for drinks. My methods divide them by string Type (Alcohol, Juice or Addition). First method don't use list AllIngredients yet, because there are only Alcohols. In second method user can choose on checklist juices (of course also alcohols on first and additions on third method). Later list of alcohols and list of juices are going to AllIngredients[0] and AllIngredients[1]. This is list of lists. Third method works similarly: user choose additions, list is going to AllIngredients[2]. On views every elements are forwarded by hidden inputs, so I have all previous data in every method. And here I have problem: when I entered to FinalDrinks (fourth method) in AllIngredients[1] I always have "Cola"! Whatever I choose (I have in database three juices: cola, orange juice and water), always in FinalDrinks I have a cola (cola id = 2). When I choose two or three drinks, cola is always first. Even if I choose orange juice and water, I have cola and orange juice.

I checked it by breakpoints, the problem is in the end of third method. I set two breakpoints: one on line "AllIngredients.Add(additions);" in third method - here everything is still OK, second at the beginning of for in FinalDrinks - here in AllIngredients[1] I have cola.

Interestingly, I used similar methods, with alcohols and additions everything works correct. I haven't any idea what can I broke between end of the third method and beginning of the fourth.

I hope one of You have any idea what is wrong here.

Best regards,
Kamil

EDIT:
I put here also a View for ThirdStep:

```
@model List<List<DrinkItUp.Models.Ingredient>>
<h2>Your alcohols:</h2>

@foreach (var userAlcohols in Model[0])
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => userAlcohols.IngredientName)
}

<h2>Your juices:</h2>
@foreach (var juices in Model[1])
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => juices.IngredientName)
}

<form asp-action="FinalDrinks" asp-controller="DrinkItUp" method="post" role="form">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        @{
            for (var i = 0; i < Model[0].Count(); i++)
            {
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[0][i].IsChecked" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[0][i].Id" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[0][i].IngredientName" />
                <br />
            }
        }
        @{
            for (var i = 0; i < Model[1].Count(); i++)
            {
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[1][i].IsChecked" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[1][i].Id" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[1][i].IngredientName" />
                <br />
            }
        }
        <h2>Choose yur additions:</h2>
        <div class="checkbox checkboxlist">
            @{
                for (var i = 0; i < Model[2].Count(); i++)
                {
                    <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model[2][i].IsChecked" />
                    <label asp-for="@Model[2][i].Id">@Model[2][i].IngredientName</label>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[2][i].Id" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[2][i].IngredientName" />
                    <br />
                }
            }
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <button type="submit">Go to next step!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

But this View don't change anything in AllIngredients[1]. What's curious, in identical way I'm sending data between First & Second Step, Second & Third and when I for tests display all ingredients in FinalDrinks, I also everything have correct.

EDIT 2:
I maked more breakpoints and I discover another think: in View also everything with list AllIngredients[1] is OK. I set last breakpoint on for with Model[2] in View and here in AllIngredients[1] is water, clicked continue, stop again on "{" FinalDrinks method in controller and... have a f**king cola! Why?! In the meanwhile I have only button to send form.

Comment: Hi @Kamil, welcome to Stackoverflow. To me your question looks quite complex. Can you provide a more condensed, clearer code snippet that covers your issue? Eventually this can speed up the responses you get. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you already discovered that the issue is happening after `ThirdStep` and before `FinalDrinks`, I'm not sure what you expect us to do with the code of the methods. The bug has to be somewhere in the view

Comment: @Kevin Gosse Yes, I know a place but I can't find there nothing wrong. I edited the post to add a view for ThirdStep.

Comment: @Konstantin A. Magg The problem is just I didn't know where I make mistake. I know only when the list AllIngredients[1] changes (by breakpoints). Maybe something is wrong with View, I added a View to my post.